# Wpf WebBrowser navigate throws COM exception

Tags: wpf

[image]

[image]
This is the code I was using, when I use webbrowser navigate to a page, it throws a COM exception. Is there any help here? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show details about the exception (click "View Detail...")? Also, if you set a breakpoint there, what is the content of the `Uri` variable that you're trying to navigate to?

Comment: I'm using System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser. And I'm sure that the html page I'm navigating to is OK because sometings I can navigate to it successfully, but sometimes cannot and I come across this issue.

Comment: Now I'm using an AvalongDoc third-party control named "LayoutAutoHideWindowControl" to accommodate the webbrowser, the third-party control can help me to autohide/show the webbrowser in my app, if the webbrowser is always shown, the navigation works fine all the time. But if it's hidden, onece I mouse over the third-party anchor to show the webbrowser up, it will trigger the code I attached and I encountered this issue. The third-party control I'm saying is derived from HwndHost which is regarded as the host control for a Win32 control, the control itself works fine.

Comment: Well, that's something that you should have mentioned in your original post.  I'm not 100% sure, but it could be an issue of the control not being fully loaded at the time you try to navigate.  Attach `Loaded` event handler to your browser control and execute the navigation code then.  See if it helps.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Anyway, I'm using the same code on the same machine

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm sure that the navigation I'm doing is after the control is loaded.

Comment: Well, why not give it a try.  I don't see anywhere in your code that checks if browser is loaded after it's shown again through that AvalonDock control and that could be the issue.  Try navigating to other pages, like `google.com`.  If the error occurs in those cases as well, then you know it's not your Uri.  Furthermore, this discussion is getting too long for comments section.  So, please move the information you've revealed here into your original post and then cleanup those comments.

Comment: I changed the Uri to another page and navigate with the same code, it still throw the excpcetion. The WebBrowser.IsLoaded is false at that moment.

Comment: @cswang in future posts, please consider posting code as text rather then screenshots. It makes reading easier so more people will be interested in answering your question.
You can use the exception window's 'copy exception details' link and then paste the relevant parts in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in our conversation, your `WebBrowser` control is not loaded at the time you're trying to navigate.  Therefore, you need to create a `Loaded` event handler and place your navigation code into that.

```
webBrowser.Loaded += WebBrowser_Loaded; // or in XAML

void WebBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your navigation code here or set a flag
}
```

If you don't wish to go through the event route, you must, at the very least, check if the control `IsLoaded` prior to attempting navigation (in your particular scenario).

If the issue persists, create a new instance of the `WebBrowser` control and navigate through that.

```
webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
```

Comment: This doesn't work as well. Because the webbrowser is hosted in a HWndHost, as you said, if the webbrowser is not loaded, then I do nothing but just delay the navigation into the loaded method, but at that point in time, if I just goes out of the code I mean the webbrowser didn't do anything, there will be another exception saying "BuildWindowCore failed to return the hosted child window handle." It seems like that I must let the webbrowser do something